# How to create a config file for Tessearct with gImageReader?

Tags: tesseract

I'm trying to prevent Tesseract from using ligatures (e.g. "fi" in 2 characters becomes "ﬁ" in just one) and found that one can add a parameter to the engine configuration file [to do just that](https://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2015/09/11/ligatures-in-tesseract-ocr-output/).

However I'm unable to locate this file in the `tessdata` directory of my gImageReader installation...

How can I create one, in terms of format, name, and other potential syntax requisites?

Answer (score 0):

You may need unpack `.traineddata` file to add an entry to the `unicharambigs` file with something like below and then repack it.

`1  ﬁ   2   fi  1`

See the doc: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract-3.03%E2%80%933.05#the-unicharambigs-file